# how to keep divs from wrapping to a new line

Tags: css, positioning

I have a series of *boxes*, first of which is 3*(+margins) larger than the rest. They *should* line up in a nice grid like so.

```
 + + + = =
 + + + = =
 + + + = =
 = = = = =
```

however what i'm getting is

```
 + + + = =
 + + + = =
 + + + = =
       = =
 = = =
```

the *boxes* are all divs, no container. here is their css

```
.userBox {
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

[See a live example of what i'm doing](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/yAzQA/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take into consideration the paddings as well.. (*if you notice really good, your big box does not align at the bottom with the ones next to it..*)

so the height of the big box should be 396 and not 400..

That is because your boxes are

- each one 100px(height) + 8px(borders). All three = 324px
- 40px(margins) between them. All two = 80px
- all together = 404px
- your box needs to be 404px (including the 8px border) so it should be 396px height..

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yAzQA/5/

---

**By the way**

You can do it with CSS only (*for modern browsers*)

```
.userBox {
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
.userBox:first-child{
    width:396px;
    height:396px;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/yAzQA/14/

Comment: blah beaten :) Was just about to post a comment saying why are using JS to do something so easily with CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

When I added an extra 2px to the height of the smaller .userBox it worked perfectly.

Also adding this to .userBox fixed as well:
"padding: 1px 0;"

Answer (score 0):

I changed height to 396 and it works fine.

```
$(".userBox").css({height: 100, width: 100}).filter(":first").css({height: 396, width: 400});
```